# Stored/flexible geom

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get a variable geom type using ggplot2 in a Shiny plot.

```
if (type == "column") {
    geom <- geom_col() 
} else {
    geom <- geom_line() + geom_point()
}

qplot(1:10, 1:10) + geom
```

This works if we remove the "geom_point" however combining them doesn't return the expression but is rather evaluated separately (which is impossible: cannot add ggproto objects together). Is there some sort of work around that doesn't require storing the plot and then adding the geom?

Comment: I can't reproduce it, but just a wild guess what happens if you wrap the `else` with a `list` as follows:  `geom <- list(geom_line() + geom_point())`?

Comment: No good sorry: still tries to evaluate `geom_col() + geom_point()` inside the list function which is still impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *does* work if you store the `geom`s in a `list`

```
my_geom <- function(type)
    if (type == "column") list(geom_col()) else list(geom_line(), geom_point())

qplot(1:10, 1:10) + my_geom("column")
```

[image]

```
qplot(1:10, 1:10) + my_geom("other")
```

[image]